# Parsing parameters to express endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, express-gateway

I have several express endpoints running which are querying a database. I'm trying to parse parameters in my express-gateway like this:

```
paths: ['/users', '/users/:userId']
```

The user endpoint is running on localhost and `/users` does return all users as intended. The problem is that `/users/:userId` also returns all users - it should only return one.

When i try to call the endpoint without the gateway it is working fine (http://localhost:3000/users/F692D717-F304-4D9B-A302-44F143923A93/)

But it's not working through the gateway. It seems like it never reaches the last endpoint or doesn't parse the parameter.

My `gateway.config.yml`:

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  users:
    host: "*"
    paths: ['/users', '/users/:userId']
  accounts:
    host: "*"
    paths: '/accounts'
  companies:
    host: "*"
    paths: '/companies'
serviceEndpoints:
  users:
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users'
  accounts:
    url: 'http://localhost:3002/accounts'
  companies:
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/companies'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  users:
    apiEndpoints:
      - users
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: users 
              changeOrigin: false
              ignorePath: true
  accounts:
    apiEndpoints:
      - accounts
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: accounts 
              changeOrigin: false
              ignorePath: true
  companies:
    apiEndpoints:
      - companies
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: companies 
              changeOrigin: false
              ignorePath: true
```

Comment: I use express in my app and I did something similar to you. I used the regex way for that and did it with only one route with this param '/db/user/(:newUser)?'. Could you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Under the proxy policy action for a given endpoint i need to set `prependPath:false`. I can't seem to find a reason inside the documentation.

Final `gateway.config.yml`:

```
 http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  users:
    host: "*"
    paths: ['/users', '/users/:userId']
  accounts:
    host: "*"
    paths: '/accounts'
  companies:
    host: "*"
    paths: '/companies'
serviceEndpoints:
  users:
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users'
  accounts:
    url: 'http://localhost:3002/accounts'
  companies:
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/companies'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  users:
    apiEndpoints:
      - users
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: users 
              changeOrigin: false
              prependPath: false
  accounts:
    apiEndpoints:
      - accounts
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: accounts 
              changeOrigin: false
              prependPath: false
  companies:
    apiEndpoints:
      - companies
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: companies 
              changeOrigin: false
              prependPath: false
```

Comment: `prependPath` defaults to `true`.  What this means is that the Service Endpoint URL path will be prefixed to the incoming request path.  With `prependPath` equal to `true`, an incoming API Endpoint request to `/users/12345` with a Service Endpoint of `http://localhost:3000/users` will proxy to `http://localhost:3000/users/users/12345`.  Setting `prependPath` to `false` ignores the Service Endpoint path altogether.  Alternatively, you could remove the `prependPath: false` declaration and remove the paths from your Service Endpoints. That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `ignorePath` to `false`? That should do the trick or alternatively, just remove the option at all from the file since its default value is `false`

Comment: If i set `ignorePath: false` i get this error when trying to access my api endpoint: `{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."
}`